# Text Label is not shown even after code compilation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var pictures = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

        for item in items{
            if item.hasSuffix("@3x"){
                pictures.append(item)
            }
        }
        print(pictures)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Country", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = pictures[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

I am trying to assign the row with the text label of files that I have in my file manager/folder. My code runs correctly but the text label of the file name with suffix "@3x" is not visible. Kindly help.

Comment: Unrelated but you can replace the loop with `pictures = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "@3x", inDirectory: nil)`. `FileManager` is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `reloadData` method on `tableView` once the fetching is complete. Here's is the code:

```
var pictures = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fm = FileManager.default
    let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
    let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

    for item in items{
        if item.hasSuffix("@3x"){
            pictures.append(item)
        }
    }
    print(pictures)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I have check editing the code you suggested but still no output. Is it possible that the row number returned is 0? Hence unable to assign cell label. How can I check that.